# How to determine which service made the app's process run?

Tags: android, service, process

My non sticky service is getting called after the app has been killed. The log shows that:

```
 I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc 26129:****/u0a311 for service com.****/com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService
```

Then my MultiDexApplication class's onCreate is getting called. Is there any way to know that it got launched due to urbanairship's service and not that the app has been launched by the user? Cause different actions are taken if the app was simply launched by the os. I don't want to run this services in a different process.

The EventService is declared in my manifest:

```
<service
    android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService"
    android:label="Event Service" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: `I don't want to run this services in a different process.` what does it mean?

Comment: @pskink In my manifest, I can put android:process=":process name" for the EventService, which makes it run on a different process.

Comment: so if you  `"don't want to run this services in a different process."` then dont use  `"android:process"` attribute

Comment: @pskink Im not. I said that cause I want a solution without running the service in a different process.

Comment: Moving the service to a different process is not the answer. Your Application will be called for every process as well. Several things can start your process - push notifications (broadcasts), service being restarted, alarms, user opening the app, etc... 

The only real way to determine if the user started the app is to wait for an activity to start. Can the action wait til then?

Comment: @ralepinski urbanairship should run all the time. However when its service is waking up, it is launching the process of the app. So I need to know if the app's process was launched due to urbanairship or another reason.

Comment: @ZiadHalabi You cant determine that from the Application. If you could explain what you are trying to accomplish we may be able to help you come up with an alternative approach.